# Is there a way to report spam or fake news to Google?

Tags: google-news

Today I noticed a spam link (from a website with a fake-news-sounding name) on my Google News feed. My first thought was to flag this as not news or as unwanted, but I wasn't able to find any option to do this.

How can I report spam or fake news to Google so they can filter it from Google News?

---

*Post-script:*
I feel the need to clarify because "fake news" in my post seems to be inviting misinterpretation. I do NOT mean "fake news" in the Trumpian sense. That is, my goal is not to flag news stories that run counter to my personal beliefs.

Rather, I mean "fake news" quite literally. Spam purveyors masquerading as news outlets.

I was getting a flurry of spam "stories" on my feed from sites with names like "West Cost Newz" (I don't remember the exact names -- there were several). The headlines would be along the lines of "Payday Loans Hot Pensacola Low Interest Save". The news-like name of the site was leading Google to include this spam in the news content it aggregates for Google News.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can report sites that violate Google News' quality guidelines for spam here:

https://support.google.com/news/contact/report_news

Answer (score 2):

If the article is labeled as "Fact Check", then yes, there is.

From [Fix settings & report problems in Google News](https://support.google.com/news/answer/6085445?hl=en&ref_topic=2428811)

> Other problems might include:
>
> - An outdated article
> - A wrong headline
> - An article in the wrong section
> - Problems with page appearance or navigation
> - A blog or press release without a label
> - An article incorrectly labeled "Fact Check"
>
> If you find one of these problems, [contact us](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/contact/report_issue_content).

Comment: This is actually for reporting issues with how your website's content is appearing in Google News. However, the first link you provided included a link to the appropriate form further down the page, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this help page](https://support.google.com/googlenews/answer/7689843?hl=en&ref_topic=7689701), the current way is to click the "Send feedback" link at the lower left of the Google News page. Or in the app, there is a "Send feedback" option in the user menu.